# How generate the primary key from XML in Hibernate?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I have a user class:

```
public class User{
    private Long userId;
}
```

And I am using this in the xml:

```
<id name="userId" type="long" unsaved-value="null">
        <column name="USER_ID" not-null="true" />
        <generator class="native" />
</id>
```

But when I am trying to save a user object without assigning the userId to the object I am getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Field 'USER_ID' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:957)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3878)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3814)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2478)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5094)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:208)
    ... 22 more
```

I want Hibernate to generate the id for me. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `autoincrement` for USER_ID column

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD USER_ID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

`native` instruction means that your database get responsibility for generate id's. Because you not set strategy to generate id's on database side you got exception `java.sql.SQLException: Field 'USER_ID' doesn't have a default value`.